# ../ in relative URL not behaving as expected

Tags: php, relative-url

Almost all the documentation I can find tells me that using "`../`" in relative URLs goes up one level from the current directory.

So if in the file at "`html/testing/new_version/admin/login.php`"

I use the following relative URL "`../images/fail.gif`" then the server should be looking for `fail.gif` at "`html/testing/new_version/images/fail.gif`" .

But it come back with a file not found error.  It's actually looking for the file in `"html/images/fail.gif"`

Why is that?  Is this a PHP setting of some sort?

Comment: Please put up the code that you have used!

Comment: is login.php being included into a file that exists in html/  and index.php perhaps?

Comment: login.php is being included in a file that resides in the same folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the code I should include.  The file in question is quite long, at it occurs in several places in various files.